# Corda network configuration and NAT

Tags: networking, nat, corda

We are conducting a project with other partners and we are finding some challenges on network design/configuration. This project is based on Corda Open Source and we are providing Dorman, Notary and Network Map Service. Each participant will have its own node. In order to avoid traffic of sensitive data over the internet, VPN was setup among the participant’s infrastructure. As they use different cloud providers, a VPN among the environment on Azure and on AWS was established.
Three participant’s nodes (one for each partner) were setup. When we tried to connect a fourth node (for a new partner), we faced IP address conflict (use of same private IP address). This problem could be solved by NAT, however, we guess that Corda Open Source doesn’t support it.

1. Is that true? Corda Open Source doesn’t support NAT implementation?
2. Any suggestion to solve or circumvent the private IP address conflict?
3. Envisioning the near future with Corda Enterprise being released. How we can make nodes running Corda Open Source interact with other nodes running Corda Enterprise with no IP address conflict?

Comment: This question is off-topic for this site, as it is for programming related questions. You can try Network Engineering or Server Fault.

Comment: It sounds like it's already working for the first three participants. What is different about the fourth participant such that they are having issues?

Comment: The fourth participant's node got a private IP address (for instance, 192.168.x.x) already in use by other organization. By a chance worked fine for the first participants, but the IP address conflict could happen with first two participants.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Corda network map service. It will allow you to actually send a request to the network map on your current nodes and register a new node on the network.

Essentially you'll make a POST to   /network-map/publish on the network map service node.

Here's a link to the page on the corda docs : https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/network-map.html#http-network-map-protocol